# SQL Summing a Column Step by Step

Tags: sql

I think it would be better if I explained my problem through a table. I want to add on a monthly basis as follows. How is it possible?

[image: Table]

```
select Month, Name , Salary from PersonelTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum.  That would be:

```
select Month, Name, Salary,
       sum(salary) over (partition by name order by month)
from PersonelTable
```